# Hibernate @Formula annotation causing SQL exception - Table reference inappropriately inserted

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, db2

I'm facing an issue with my Spring Boot application and Hibernate. A specific entity field needs to be adjusted when retrieved, because the database table has some wrongly inserted characters in two columns. The problem is that this character can only be referenced by its hex code and Hibernate doesn't work fine with this.

Here is my code:

```
@Formula("REPLACE(NMRAZSOC, x'90', x'C9')")
private String nmrazsoc;
```

When doing a SELECT directly in the database, this works fine:

```
SELECT NUCGCCEI,
       REPLACE(NMRAZSOC, x'90', x'C9')
FROM EMPRESA
```

But somehow the @Formula is translated by Hibernate to:

```
REPLACE(e1_0.NMRAZSOC, e1_0.x'90', e1_0.x'C9')
```

That `e1_0.x'90'` is clearly wrong. Hibernate thinks that `x'90'` is a column reference, when in fact it is a character hex code.

What can I do to fix this behaviour?

As a side note, I don't have write permissions in the database to replace those characters there before the actual entity mapping, so REPLACE in `@Formula` seems to be my only option here.

The database is IBM DB2, if that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this will work `@Formula("REPLACE(NMRAZSOC, HEXTORAW('90'), HEXTORAW('C9'))")`